# Should we define Role-Playing Games

Tags: discussion, on-topic

A recent meta question asked if role-playing in video games is on topic here.  The question was focused on one held question on main, and the answers seamed focused on the question.  But it got me thinking about the scope of the site, and I didn't find an answer on a cursory search of meta.

What is a Role-Playing Game?

Is there a line we can draw between a straight up tabletop game with very little role-play elements and a 'traditional' RPG?  Is there a line between friends playing pretend or telling stories around a table and a traditional RPG?

If we have those lines of demarcation of 'what is RPG enough to be on topic', what are they?

Do we need those lines if they do not already exist?

I do not ask this because I have a strong opinion one way or the other, but purely to know the scope of the site.  I do not want to change the scope of the site (in this particular case), just to document where those limits are, if there are any.

Comment: This could probably be edited to be more concise...

Comment: Possibly a duplicate of [What kind of questions can I ask here?](http://meta.rpg.stackexchange.com/q/544) Is this answered there?

Comment: @SevenSidedDie No, this is more a "ok, so what does that actually mean, now that we have listed the games we cover."

Comment: Is there a practical site-running problem this is tackling that isn't already tackled there? Tackling the theoretical question of “what is an RPG” would otherwise seem to be a main-site question. What does having a definition add when we already have it sorted out what's on-topic?

Comment: @SevenSidedDie It's not a main site question, because it is looking for where to cast close-as-off-topic votes on main.  Is 'just because I call what we are doing RP' enough to be on topic.

Comment: @SevenSidedDie and I fully admit an answer of  "No, we cant define the terms with any rigidity" is a good answer.

Comment: I'm pretty sure this is already answered there then, as the question there is about what is on and off topic and by extension how to decide whether to cast an off-topic-close-vote on a question.

Comment: @SevenSidedDie No.  It absolutely does not.  That says "Role playing games are on topic."  ... This is asking "where is what THEY call a role playing game, not a role playing game"

Comment: You've lost me. Is your question maybe different than what you've written above? Twice you've mentioned people *calling* something roleplaying or a roleplaying game, which makes me think that might be the crucial difference in our understanding of what you're asking, but it appears nowhere in the question.

Comment: @SevenSidedDie It apparently is in the question, as BESW answered the question I asked.  The question asked "where does a table-top game turn into an RPG" and "Where telling stories in a group turns into an RPG", at which point these activities become on-topic.

Comment: Okay. “Where does a TT game / group storytelling turn into an RPG” is a main-site question. “What is an RPG (in the context of what is on and off topic here)” is a duplicate of our other question.

Comment: It's also a duplicate of [What do you class as a "Role-playing Game"?](http://meta.rpg.stackexchange.com/q/3155) (which is also closed as a duplicate of [What kind of questions can I ask here?](http://meta.rpg.stackexchange.com/q/544)).

Comment: @SevenSidedDie How are questions about how to judge main site questions, themselves main site questions?

Comment: @SevenSidedDie And how does a copy-paste out of wikipedia help me vote to close or open a question?

Comment: @SevenSidedDie Just because YOU  dont understand the question does not mean you should arbitrarily close it, as it is absolutely not a duplicate!

Comment: I was just paraphrasing what you were saying. “Where does a TT game / group storytelling turn into an RPG” *is* a main-site question, “Where does a TT game / group storytelling turn into an RPG (for the purpose of what's on and off topic)” is a meta-site question. Regardless, we already have that question answered for the purposes of the site. If the answers are insufficient, bounty, etc. as usual.

Comment: @SevenSidedDie YOU CANT BOUNTY ON META!

Comment: Oh! So you can't. Sorry. It's been bumped anyway since I made an edit to one of the answers.

Comment: @SevenSidedDie Even though you are 100% objectively wrong on every single thing you have said in this comment stream, I no longer have the emotional willpower.  Congratulations, you have overmoterated again.

Comment: Moderators are supposed to take a more direct hand on meta. This post will still be here tomorrow and it will still have a [reopen] button below it. If you can edit it to show how it's not a duplicate of either of those question and not a main-site question, then it could be reopened.

Comment: @SevenSidedDie You are the ONLY ONE who saw it as a main site question.  You are THE ONLY ONE who thinks its a duplicate.  You are the ONLY ONE who is wrong.

Comment: You should probably go for a walk and calm down.

Comment: @SevenSidedDie You should probably re-open the question, or close it as something OTHER than a duplicate of something it obviously is not.

Comment: I could close it as a duplicate of [What do you class as a "Role-playing Game"?](http://meta.rpg.stackexchange.com/q/3155), but since that's closed as a duplicate of [What kind of questions can I ask here?](http://meta.rpg.stackexchange.com/q/544) already, it seems unnecessary.

Comment: @SevenSidedDie Can you honestly look at BESW's answer can say "Yeah that accepted answer is in the same vein as the answers to the question this is being closed as duplicate of."

Comment: It's not in the same vein, yeah. That's why I probed to find out what site-management issue you were trying to solve, since the theoretical line between RPGs and everything else is interesting, but not on-topic on Meta without a site-management issue connected to it. And when you clarified that it is about figuring out what questions are on/off-topic, I pointed out we already have that meta question.

Comment: @SevenSidedDie The meta question you pointed out... Does not even come close to covering this.  It lists what types of games are on topic, but does not make any effort to define them for *this community*.

Comment: Which is why I asked what site-management purpose trying to define it has. We declined to attempt (the frankly impossible task of) strictly defining RPGs years ago, settled on defining what is and isn't on topic in pragmatic terms instead, and I have closed this second “What's an RPG?” question as another duplicate of that existing meta. I expect we will get a third “But what counts as an RPG?” meta Q asked again years from now, and it will also be closed a duplicate.

Comment: @SevenSidedDie It was never documented, or poorly documented, that you decided not to define rpgs.  BESW's answer documents that.  That ALONE makes it a valuable site management question.

Comment: It describe the status quo that “we know it when we see it”, but that observation can be independently arrived at by reading the Q&A this is marked as duplicate of. Which is why it's marked as a duplicate.

Comment: @SevenSidedDie we have very different ideas about what is obvious, because I cannot naturally come to the same conclusion as you did.

Comment: I don't think there's been time enough to calm down and actually read it. In particular, regarding this question, the top answer there lists what is on topic, what is off topic, and then notes “We make exceptions for questions that are primarily about something on the do list that simply uses or refers to one of the do nots in some way.” That fully covers the recent video-game situation this question was inspired by, and it covers this question about what counts as an RPG for the purposes of RPG.se. The examples in this question here are all covered there already. Just read it and apply it.

Comment: @SevenSidedDie I have read that answer, repeatedly, in the past.  You are absolutely wrong in that it covers anything in this question.  If it did, *I wouldn't have asked this*!

Comment: It does. Worked example for whether “friends playing pretend or telling stories around a table” is on-topic/an RPG-for-our-purposes: Does it match any of the **do** items? The closest is “freeforming”, but storytelling doesn't involve “socially-mediated procedures that accomplish what traditional mechanics do”, so it doesn't match. Therefore friends storytelling or playing pretend is off topic, unless they're using game-like social procedures for it. If they are, then it's on-topic. So your main example is covered there.

Comment: I also don't see what this question covers that's not covered by the previous question.  "What is an RPG" is a contentious question not relevant to governance of the site.  "What kind of questions are on topic here" is. The lead answer to the other question covers the couple examples in this question more than adequately; if there are other cases it doesn't please bring them up specifically.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

No, we can't and shouldn't draft a hard definition of RPGs.

Right now we've got a "know it when we see it" sort of attitude, and it works very well at least 95% of the time. The RPG medium is vastly diverse, and historically attempts to define it have been... fraught. Any definition will likely accidentally exclude stuff we really think ought to be on topic, and spark arguments in response.

Answer (score 6):

### Role-playing games are games where we do role-playing.

And that's as @BESW rightly said about as much of a definition that we need. It is appropriate to ask a question about roleplaying in game context regardless of the medium used - be it in-person session, Roll20, MUD, LARP, freeform over e-mail or countless others.

In fact current practice shows that [questions less focused on the "game" part are also OK](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/76561/how-deep-information-should-players-have-in-a-political-negotiation-focused-edu) (like ones that deal with educational effort or creating a safe psychodrama space), so I would posit that it's the playing of a role that's central to the experience. That said, defining "roleplaying" is even more challenging and we should definitely not attempt to do it.

In regard to the video-game question, it is not for us to decide arbitrarily whether the whole group is on or off topic here - we should consider these edge cases individually and carefully decide whether roleplaying is in the core of the question or not.